# Identify the p-checkbox where an event occurs in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-checkbox

I would like to know if there is a way to identify my checkbox, along with the event that occurs when it is selected, that is, if I can put a type of ID and pass it to my .ts file, along with the true or false that responds to me the event.

```
<p-checkbox name="reviewed" inputId="reviewed" [(ngModel)]="data.reviewed"
  [binary]="true" (onChange)="checkValue(data.reviewed)">
</p-checkbox>
```

```
checkValue(event: any){
    //here I want to recerive the checkbox ID;
    console.log(event);
}
```

Comment: So you should pass the `$event` into the method, not `data.reviewed`

Comment: I need the data.reviewed for other functionalities that I am doing, I would like to know if I can pass more than one value in the onChange

Comment: Yes you can, just try it.

Comment: you can get the event object like this `(onChange)="checkValue($event)`you will get the checked  value and original mouse event but my answer show an easy way to do it 

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I finally decided to change a few things in the rest of the code and decided to do it by passing only the $event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can create a template variable for the checkbox component then pass the **inputId**

```html
<p-checkbox name="reviewed" inputId="reviewed" [(ngModel)]="data.reviewed"
  [binary]="true" (onChange)="checkValue(checkElm.inputId ,data.reviewed)" #checkElm>
</p-checkbox>
```

*component.ts*

```js
checkValue(id,event: any){
  //here I want to recerive the checkbox ID;
}
```

if you want you can just pass the id as hardcoded value

```html
<p-checkbox name="reviewed" inputId="reviewed" [(ngModel)]="data.reviewed"
  [binary]="true" (onChange)="checkValue('reviewed',data.reviewed)" >
</p-checkbox>
```

Comment: Thanks, with your first option it worked for me!